# WPF display content in two different ways

Tags: wpf, contentcontrol

I writing something like HexEditor in WPF.
And i need to display for example sequence of bytes on the same ContentControl in two different ways.

```
23 20 54 68 69 73 20 76 69 6d 69 6e 66 6f 20   Hello World!
```

What is the right way to achive this?
I dont want to use TWO controlls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use binding with a converter.

```
<TextBox Text={Binding yourValue, Converter=YOURBOTHVALUESCONVERTER}/>
```

The converter will take in parameter your value in hexadecimal, and return this string and the string representation (your second data to print)